# Superelliptic curves

Tags: reference-request, diophantine-equations

I'm trying to find information on superelliptic curves and how to solve them over the integers. The equation is $$y^k = f(x)$$ where $k=3$ and $f$ has degree $d=3$. Does anyone know any references/books/links that may help me? I'm finding a few PDF's but they all assume $gcd(k,d)=1$.

Comment: You mean hyperelliptic curves, don't you? Superelliptic means something quite different IIRC.

Comment: @user_of_math No it is superelliptic. Hyperelliptic curves deal with $d > 4$.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "solve them over integers"?

The assumption gcd(k, d)=1 is simply to assure that the degree d cyclic covering is tame.  Usually, people will call a curve "superelliptic" if it is of the form $$y^k = f(x)$$ for any degree $d > 3$ polynomial $f(x)$.